# Removing a Jailbreak from an iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I jailbroke my iOS Device, but now I want to remove it. I can put the device on my iCloud from the phone now, but when I perform the restore process, will iCloud be locked? I'm not sure how it works, and I don't want to have any chance of having it locked. Will it become locked?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question; no, iCloud will not become locked... *if you remove the jailbreak correctly.*

Following a guide [like this one](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/unjailbreak-your-iphone-3601679/) should help you get your iDevice back to its natural iOS state.

**Steps:**

1. Connect your iPhone to a Mac using the USB Cable.
2. If you have a passcode on your iPhone, enter the passcode to unlock it.
3. Click Settings > iCloud > Find My iPhone and set it to Off.
4. Enter your Apple ID password and tap Turn Off.
5. Click the Devices icon in iTunes and choose your iPhone.
6. Select This Computer under Backups.
7. Click Backup Now and choose Backup Apps from the Alert Window.
8. Click Restore iPhone and tap Restore in the alert window.

> Apple iTunes will now restore your iPhone to its original software state. You may need to download the latest version of iOS from Apple, and it may take a while for the installation to complete. Follow the instructions on-screen to restore your iPhone from the backup you created earlier.